# Opening a previous form when one is closed

Tags: c#

First of all, I am a newcomer to C# and programming in general. I've searched pretty thoroughly, but I can only find instances where someone wants to open another form and hide the one that the button was pressed on.

In this instance, I'm having issues with my program continuously running when I press the (X) on any form other than the main "Form1".The form-to-form navigation works fine. i.e.: clicking a button hides the main window and opens the appropriate form, and the "back" button on that form hides itself and shows (I guess another instance) of the previous "main" form. --I could probably use some guidance in that, too. lol

I wouldn't mind if it closed the entire application if the X was pressed, but I need to have the "X" present on all windows and all windows need to exit the entire app if the X is pressed. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Code:

**Form1:**

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            public void btnTransaction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Transaction transactionForm = new Transaction();
                Form mainForm = this;
                transactionForm.Show();
                mainForm.Hide();
            }
        }
```

**Transaction Form:**

```
    public partial class Transaction : Form
        {
            public Transaction()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form1 mainForm = new Form1(); //not sure if I'm doing this right..
                this.Hide();                  //I don't know how to "reuse" the original Form1
                mainForm.Show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: after opening `Form1` do u have any use of `Transaction ` form ?

Comment: Is the pageflow neccesarily spreaded to different forms or could you redesign you application and work with userControls (same behavior like forms without the window around) within a tabControl or on a single panel (with simply managing the visibility)?

Comment: Thanks for all of the help guys! This forum has been very helpful! Now I understand why the planning phase is so important :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you create an MDI Container for this. Drag and drop a MenuStrip from the ToolBox to Form1 and then create a ToolStripMenuItem "form2" in MenuStrip.
Now you can call your form2 in form1 like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IsMdiContainer = true;
        }
        Form2 frm2;
        public void CreateMdiChild<T>(ref T t) where T : Form, new()
        {
            if (t == null || t.IsDisposed)
            {
                t = new T();
                t.MdiParent = this;
                t.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                if (t.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    t.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                else
                {
                    t.Activate();
                }
            }
        }
        private void form2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateMdiChild<Form2>(ref frm2);
        }
    }
```

When by clicking ToolStripMenuItem you fire ToolStripmenuItem event ,  it will show Form2 as child in form1 i.e the mdi container and will be closed when you close form1.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I think I will have to completely start over, as my code already contains many other statements and functions I didn't include in the post that are going to break because of the auto-generated jibberish I don't quite understand yet.

Comment: I wonder when someone accepts the answer but doesn't upvote, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public partial class Transaction : Form
    {
        Form1 _mainForm;

        public Transaction(Form1 mainForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mainForm = mainForm;
        }
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();  //since you always create a new one in Form1
            _mainForm.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the use `Form.ShowDialog()`

When this method is called, the code following (code below the 'ShowDialog()') it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
    this.Hide();                 
    mainForm.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ShowDialog()` method that will require the user to interact with the new form before returning to the previous form. For instance you could try this:

```
public void btnTransaction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var transactionForm = new Transaction())
    {
      this.Hide();
      if (transactionForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          this.Show();
      }
    }
}
```

The `DialogResult` is something you can set on the `TransactionForm` like so:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

That's a pretty standard way of forcing interaction on a new form.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    menu menu = new menu("administrator");
    menu.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

//happy coding